# complete setup openfire with xmppframework on iphone

Tags: iphone, openfire, xmppframework

I am new to openfire and xmppframework. I have setup the openfire and xmppframe work on my system both are working fine individually. xmppframework working fine with googletalk.

But I can't find a way to connect my xmppframework with my openfire server.

Can anybody please tell me how to setup the openfire server with the xmppframework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to make any specific changes to your Openfire server to work with Xmppframework, you just need to ensure that the xmpp.domain property matches your domain for the server - this is found under Server -> Server Manager -> System Properties on the Openfire admin panel.

Once you've done that, look at your Xmppframework code and where you configured it for Googletalk, change the line:

```
    [xmppStream setHostName:@"domain.com"];
```

Where domain.com should be whatever your server domain is (and is the same as the xmpp.domain property). You will need to do the same with `[xmppStream setMyJID:@"..."]` and the password.

If you're still having problems, please try to be more specific where you need help and what errors you're facing.

Comment: Do you mean if I have domain www.etubez.com then I should set host name as etubez.com and I should setMyJID to abc@etubez.com?

Comment: Hello there Marc ! I have the same issue with an open fire server. Do you have a client that works with an Open Fire server?

Comment: @danipralea What issue do you have specifically? What error messages are you getting? Can you connect to your OpenFire server using a client such as Psi?

Comment: I can connect to my open fire server with any mac client in any way. I can connect to my jabber accounts from my iOS app, I can connect with other apps to my open fire server, I just can't connect from my own iOS app to my open fire server. Some help please? :)

Comment: @danipralea you would need to show some code. It's impossible to debug without seeing what you've got so far. Please start a new question and I and others will have a look.

Comment: If you are willing to help a desperate programmer regarding this issue, then you may want to send me your e-mail addres at `praleadanut@gmail.com` and I can send you the entire project (I'm not trying to be pesky, only a pinpoint for my problem is needed). Thanks in advance. I'm struggling with this one for months now. I've pretty much abandoned trying to make it work... That's how much I worked on it :)